# XBAP Application, can these work in Google Chrome?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, xbap

I'm developing a .NET 3.5 XBAP application that runs perfectly fine in FF3 and IE6/7 etc. I'm just wondering if its possible to get these to run under other browsers, specifically (as its in the limelight at the moment) Google Chrome.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

XBAP applications do work in google chrome, however you have to set your environments PATH variable to the directory where xpcom.dll is located.

for example SET PATH=PATH;"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"

Comment: why crome don't open the internet explorer?

Comment: Chrome is just downloading the file for me

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, XBAPs do not work in Google Chrome.  I've gotten it to run once, somehow, but every time there after I've received an error that the browser cannot locate xpcom.dll.  Apparently this error occurs for more than just XBAP applications.  From what I've read users will have to wait for a fix seeing as Chrome is still in beta.

**Update:**

Looks like it's not going to be fixed: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4051

Comment: Good enough answer for me :) I get the same, lets hope they fix it soon because XBAP deployment I'm learning to love!

Comment: Have you guys tried this with the development channel version of Chrome? It's no longer in beta.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative solution that still requires Firefox to be installed, but you copy DLLs instead of modifying the PATH:

http://adrianbega.blogspot.com/2009/04/execute-xbap-in-google-chrome.html

Answer (score 2):

First thing required here is to make the .Net framework 3.5 installed, once its done check whether the application is working in Mozilla Firefox, because it uses the plugin of Mozilla, if there is some issue in Mozilla, execute the `aspnet_regiis.exe -iru` from Visual Studio command prompt with administrative priviledge, then set Path variable to `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox` and add the following DLLs to the location `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application`

- mozalloc.dll
- mozcpp19.dll
- mozcrt19.dll
- mozjs.dll
- mozsqlite3.dll
- nspr4.dll
- nss3.dll
- nssutil3.dll
- plc4.dll
- plds4.dll
- smime3.dll
- ssl3.dll
- test.txt
- xpcom.dll
- xul.dll

and restart the browser, and check the application, if it still shows the plugin crashed, try re-installing the framework first and then Mozilla, also for Windows 7, mozilla requires to put the NPWPF.dll to the location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\plugins`.

After this whole lot of hell, the application may still not debug, then publish the XBAP application and check with file and keep your finger crossed as it may work this time, this is how I made my application work in my system and checked for 5 more systems, so hope it resolve your problem too.