# Does a wpf XBAP application only run in Internet Explorer?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, xbap

Or does it also run in other browsers?  The information I'm reading is confusing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the MSDN docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716877.aspx

There is a previous thread about this as well: [XBAP Application, can these work in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74986/xbap-application-can-these-work-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

It can also run in Firefox [And might likely work for other NetScape-Plugin-Aware browsers].

Check this video for more info:

http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=6887