# Can silverlight help porting a wpf desktop application on the web?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, silverlight

I have developed a desktop application with c# and wpf. Next step is to develop an intranet web application which shares some business logic with the desktop one.
I have absolutely no experience with silverlight and asp.net.

Can Silverlight improve the portability of existent code and wpf user controls compared to asp.net ?

Are there additional alternative ways ?

My target O.S. is windows 2003 Server, so I cannot use the most recent technologies and I'm limited to .net 4.0 framework.

Comment: If you have experience with WPF, you have experience with Silverlight... It's a web version of WPF. You can find controls like Datagrids, Tab etc (XAML + C#). You can use some code but you should rewrite. Indeed Silverlight has less functionality than WPF (WPF Light). But warn of [Silverlight Support Lifecycle](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&c2=12905)

Comment: Note that you can find a good [WPF-Silverlight Comparison Whitepaper](http://wpfslguidance.codeplex.com/releases/view/30311)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Silverlight is very similar to WPF, although not 1:1.

Another option that would be easier to port is a WPF browser application - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx

Comment: I suppose Silverlight and Wpf browser applications are closely tied to Microsoft Browser, aren't they ? Besides I forgot to mention that my application is a front end for a database. No concern on having clients directly accessing database from intranet, but I don't know if it is easy from silverlight.

Comment: Silverlight will work in any browser that supports the plugin - which is basically any non-mobile Windows or Mac browser. WPF browser applications are meant for IE, although with some finagling, they will run in Chrome or FF - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337155/how-can-i-get-my-xbap-to-run-in-my-browser-instead-of-downloading-it-on-windows.

Regarding databases, Silverlight doesn't get along well with them, typically you'd use a WCF service in between, although some libraries exist, I can't verify how well they work, for example: http://silverlight4sqllib.codeplex.com/