# How to open xbap in FireFox 39.0 & Chrome in Windows 8.1 pro 64bit

Tags: wpf, google-chrome, firefox, .net-3.5, xbap

i have published a xbap(wpf browser application) in frame work 3.5

now i copied C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Windows Presentation Foundation\NPWPF.dll

to

C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\plugins but xbap is not running, its starting download when i run it.

my system information is

windows 8.1 pro 64bit
firefox 39.0
Chrome Version 44.0.2403.89 m

but xbap is not running in both FF and Chrome, any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XBAP Application, can these work in Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74986/xbap-application-can-these-work-in-google-chrome)

Comment: thanks for reply, i am unable to run it in firefox :(, thats why i cant run it  in chrome as well, if u have npwpf.dll from xp then send it to me , may be it'll work