# Run WPF application through URL directly in Google-Chrome

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, exe

I have WPF application(.exe), which was hosted in my remote web server. 
Now I want to access WPF application from my web page by clicking respective link.

```
Response.Redirect(WPFLaunchUrl);
```

By using this, I am able lunch application in IE. But whenever I am using **Google-Chrome** then application downloading into my local system instead of running application from Hosted URL.

Could you please suggest me on this.

Comment: try to use the developer console. what header is the response giving? It shouldnt be octet stream

Comment: wpf application is a program that runs under windows os. exe files cannot be opened in any browser.

Comment: Maybe try the [ClickOnce for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickonce-for-google-chro/kekahkplibinaibelipdcikofmedafmb?hl=de) extension?

Comment: In IE browser its working as expected, but not in Chrome. Do we need to check any browser level settings?

Comment: @Jagadeesh: XBAPs are not officially supported in Chrome. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74986/xbap-application-can-these-work-in-google-chrome

Comment: @mm8 : I am not using XBAP. just normal WPF App (Application Manifest (.application))